# From dict with tuples to dict with lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary in Python containing time stamps, t, and value stamps, v, looking like this:

```
dict_example = {key1: [(t1, v1), (t2, v2), (t3, v3)],
                key2: [(t4, v4), (t5, v5), (t6, v6)],
                ...}
```

What I want to do is to make two separate dicts looking like this:

```
dict_example_timestamps = {key1: [t1, t2, t3],
                           key2: [t4, t5, t6],
                           ...}

dict_example_valuestamps = {key1: [v1, v2, v3],
                            key2: [v4, v5, v6],
                            ...}
```

That is, two separate dicts with one containing a list of timestamps per key and the other one containing a list of valuestamps per key.

I have 'succeeded' in getting all e.g. timestamps as a list but they need to be 'grouped' per key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dict_example = {"key1": [(21, 45), (23, 30), (23, 23)],
            "key2": [(10, 45), (15, 51), (56, 6)]}
dict_example_timestamps = {a:[c for c, d in b] for a, b in dict_example.items()}
dict_example_valuestamps = {a:[d for c, d in b] for a, b in dict_example.items()}
print(dict_example_timestamps)
print(dict_example_valuestamps)
```

Output:

```
{'key1': [21, 23, 23], 'key2': [10, 15, 56]}
{'key1': [45, 30, 23], 'key2': [45, 51, 6]}
```